# how to restore a minimized form from another form's button click and closing the second form too

Tags: c#, winforms

i have two forms in my application form 1 and form 2. Form 1 is main form in which i have placed a data grid view bind to a data source.
 On cell content click event i am opening another form i. e. form 2 by minimizing form 1 .

on form 2 i have 1 button "Cancel". i want that when i click on this button, Form 2 should close and form 1 should be restored in its previous position by refreshing its data source. i want to use form 2 for update purposes. when i click OK on form 2. database get updated and when i click cancel form 2 should be close and form 1 should becoming visible by refreshing its data source. data base is updated successfully but i am not able to restore form 1 to its original position.

On form 1 OnLoad event i have bind the data grid view to a data source. so i also want that when form 1 get restored it should reflect the changes i have made into it.

Thanks in Advance.

My code of form 1 loading and cell content clicking is

```
  private void Viewcashvoucher_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection();
        c.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\Accounts\\Accounts\\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        c.Open();
        string s = "Select main_key as M_KEY ,vc_type as VT, date as DATE,vc_number as VOUCH_NO,account_n as ACCOUNT,amount as AMOUNT from lgr order by date desc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, c);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        c.Close();
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a public method in form1 that restores it and refreshes the dataGridView data:

Create a public method in Form1:

```
public void RestoreAndRefresh()
    {
        this.Show();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; //Or perform the refresh rutine you want.
    }
```

In Form2 add a variable of type Form1:

```
public From1 f1Parent {get; set;}
```

When you create Form2 in Form1 just add the following lines:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.f1Parent = this;
f2Show();
```

And in the end, in Form2's Ok and Cancel buttons add these lines:

```
f1Parent.RestoreAndRefresh();
this.Close();
```

You will need to adjust RestoreAndRefresh method to your needs, but it should restore Form1.

Comment: when i am creating form 2, i am minimizing form 1. from2 f2 = new form(); f2.f!parent = this; f2.show make both form minimized. @ NDraskvic

Comment: but my updated record got reflected as per requirement. now i just want that when i create second form, 1st form should be minimized and after clicking cancel button form 2 should be closed and form 1 should be restored with refreshing values @ NDraskovic

Comment: try putting the code for minimizing Form1 after f2.Show() line. Also in Form2_Load method place a line 'this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;'. Thi should take care of displaying the forms correctly